# Story about alien race called the Venge seeking to destroy humans

Tags: story-identification, aliens

I read this Sci Fi Novel in high school but it was so long ago I can't remember the details, Author, etc.

The basic story is about a race of aliens who are called "Venge" short for Vengeance of course who are seeking to destroy humans for some past wrong. If I remember correctly they are a hive mind. That is all I can remember any help identifying the novel would be appreciated.

Comment: When were you in high school? That would help narrow down when the book was published.

Comment: I graduated in 1981 and if my memory serves me correctly I read it while I still high school or very shortly afterwards.